# HOW TO usb Lacewing::Client TO ReceiveEx Data?

Tags: c++, sockets, liblacewing

```
Lacewing::EventPump pump;
        Lacewing::Client* client = new Lacewing::Client(pump);
        client->Tag = this;
        client->onReceive(onReceiveEx);
        client->onConnect(onConnectEx);

        Lacewing::Address adb("127.0.0.1",12581,Lacewing::Address.HINT_IPv4);
        client->Connect(adb);
        pump.StartEventLoop();
```

this My code, the client Connect to the server sucessfully and the onConnectEx called as expected , but the onReceiveEx didn't called!!! client doesn't Receive anything, why?

Answer (score 0):

If ReceiveEx is not called, it means that the server has not sent any data to your client. You should ensure that your server is sending data to clients that connect to it - if not, then you should not expect ReceiveEx to be called and this is normal behavior.